# Does compilerOptions/target specify target JavaScript version for the frontend, the backend, or both?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

In Next.js `tsconfig.json` does `compilerOptions/target` specify target JavaScript version for the frontend, the backend, or both?

Is it possible to have different target versions for frontend and backend?

Comment: It's for one project/package, TypeScript does not care what the code does or where it is used. Only you can tell whether that includes frontend or backend or other code, for multiple ones or none.